# Web scraping with nested frames and javascript

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping, mechanize, frames

I want to get answers from a online chatbot.
http://talkingbox.dyndns.org:49495/braintalk?    (the ? belongs to the link)

To send a question you just have to send a simple request:

```
http://talkingbox.dyndns.org:49495/in?id=3B9054BC032E53EF691A9A1803040F1C&msg=[Here the question]
```

Source looks like this:

```
<frameset cols="*,185" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
<frameset rows="100,*,82" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
    <frame src="http://thebot.de/bt_banner.html" marginwidth="0" name="frtop" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" frameborder="no">
    <frame src="out?id=3B9054BC032E53EF691A9A1803040F1C" name="frout" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <frameset rows="100%,*" border="0" framespacing="0" frameborder="no">
        <frame src="bt_in?id=3B9054BC032E53EF691A9A1803040F1C" name="frin" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" noresize>
        <frame src="" name="frempty" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" frameborder="no" >
    </frameset>
</frameset>
<frameset frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0" rows="82,*">
    <frame src="stats?" name="fr1" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="no">
    <frame src="http://thebot.de/bt_rechts.html" name="fr2" scrolling="auto" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="no" >
</frameset>
</frameset>
```

I was using "mechanize" and beautifulsoup for web scraping but I suppose mechanize does not support dynamic webpages.

How can I get the answers in this case?

I am also looking for a solution which work good on Windows and Linux.

Comment: You can try selenuim which is good at browser automation along with its binding for phantomjs (which provides JS API for headless Webkit, Webkit is a rendering engine). http://www.realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/#.UtYORpDtn4w

Comment: what is dynamic webpage? these frameworks only know http requests, also, the link you shared is inaccessible

Comment: @Guy I think the "user317" is referring to content fetched through XHR requests, but I agree more details would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry, the link is http://talkingbox.dyndns.org:49495/braintalk? (with the ? at the end which gets cut off by stackoverflow). The Url of the frame is http://talkingbox.dyndns.org:49495/out?id=37C64A9B1561DBA2499A20372D4D7F0D the problem is that somehow the frame can not be accessed like this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I probably have to clarify that I am having problems to get the answers not to send them since the answers within a nested frame which gets dynamicly generated with JavaScript. This frame: http://talkingbox.dyndns.org:49495/out?id=37C64A9B1561DBA2499A20372D4D7F0D

Answer (score 1):

be it BeautifulSoup, mechanize, Requests or even Scrapy, loading that dynamic pages will have to be done by another step written by you.

for example, using scrapy this may look something like:

```
class TheBotSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'thebot'
    allowed_domains = ['thebot.de', 'talkingbox.dyndns.org']

    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        super(TheBotSpider, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
        self.domain = 'http://talkingbox.dyndns.org:49495/'
        self.start_urls = [self.domain + 
                           'in?id=3B9054BC032E53EF691A9A1803040F1C&msg=' + 
                           self.question]

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        url = sel.xpath('//frame[@name="frout"]/@src').extract()[0]
        yield Request(url=url, callback=dynamic_page)

    def dynamic_page(self, response):
        .... xpath to scrape answer
```

run it with a question as argument:

```
scrapy crawl thebot -a question=[Here the question]
```

for more details on how to use scrapy see [scrapy tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for task like this.

```
import requests

r = requests.get("http://talkingbox.dyndns.org:49495/in?id=3B9054BC032E53EF691A9A1803040F1C&msg=" + your_question)
```

For webpages that do not contain dynamic content, `r.text` is what you want.

Since you didn't provide more information about **dynamic webpage**, there is not much more to say.